# flutter has exited unexpectedly: "ProcessException: Failed to find "

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

when I´m building my apk I got this message,

> "Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "ProcessException: Failed to find "C:\Users\USUARIO\Documents\Diego\Proyectos\flutter_projects\firstapp\android\gradlew.bat" in the search path.
> Command: C:\Users\USUARIO\Documents\Diego\Proyectos\flutter_projects\firstapp\android\gradlew.bat ".
> A crash report has been written to C:\Users\USUARIO\Documents\Diego\Proyectos\flutter_projects\firstapp\flutter_03.log."

firstapp is my app name, by the way,ty for your helping[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94YXs.png)

Comment: flutter clean then flutter pub get then build your apk

Comment: Thank u, it works, but... what was that?

Comment: sometimes it caches methods and then Gradle can't find it again, I will post this as an answer and upvote it with click tick button so other people can user this answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**:-

1. run `flutter clean` command to clean the directories.
2. run `flutter pub get` to re-import the libraries and classes.
3. build your apk